# Trying to compile 'make' custom config vim won't work

Tags: ubuntu, vim

Hi I'm new to vim but I have been trying to compile a vim version (on ubuntu 12.04) using this configuration parameters `./configure --with-features=huge --enable-gui=gnome2 --enable-luainterp=yes --enable-pythoninterp=yes --enable-rubyinterp=yes` then according to a youtube video I was watching I had to compile it using `make` then It looks like it's compiling but It doesn't generate any extra folder or anything. Any hints?.
PS: I have my vim and .vim folders alongside with my .vimrc in the same directory level

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `make` succeeds without errors, there should be a `vim` executable in the `<working copy>/src/` folder. To install this (and the corresponding runtime files) permanently on your system (at `/usr/local/bin/vim`), execute:

```
$ sudo make install
```

Comment: Thanks this worked great, after doing this I ran vim inside usr/local/bin/ and ran downloaded all dependencies. After that It couldn't install unite though. But what's still in my mind is that it gives a kind of warning before executing vim. `neocomplete does not work this version of Vim. It requires Vim 7.3.885 or above and "if_lua" enabled Vim.
UltiSnips requires py >= 2.6 or any py3` But I already have python 2.7 and vim version according to vim itself it's 7.4b. Thanks!

Comment: You can check with `:version` whether the compilation of the language interfaces really worked. It must read `+lua` and `+python`.

Answer (score 0):

"neocomplete does not work this version of Vim. It requires Vim 7.3.885 or above and "if_lua" enabled Vim."

Maybe installing lua-devel and using the option `--with-lua-prefix=/usr/` will solve this problem.

Replace the "/usr/" with your lua-devel install path. If you are not sure, use `find / -name lua.h` to find lua.h, if the result is "/usr/local/include/lua.h", use "/usr/local/" to replace "/usr/" (don't need the "include/" subdirectory).

After installing vim, use `vim --version|grep +lua` to check whether lua enabled.